# In C++ what causes an assignment to evaluate as true or false when used in a control structure?

Tags: c++

So can someone help me grasp all the (or most of the relevant) situations of an assignment inside something like an if(...) or while(...), etc?

What I mean is like:

```
if(a = b)
```

or

```
while(a = &c)
{
}
```

etc...

When will it evaluate as true, and when will it evaluate as false? Does this change at all depending on the types used in the assignment? What about when there are pointers involved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In C++ an attribution evaluates to the value being attributed:

```
int c = 5; // evaluates to 5, as you can see if you print it out
float pi = CalculatePi(); // evaluates to the result
                          // of the call to the CalculatePi function
```

So, you statements:

```
if (a = b) { }
while (a = &c) { }
```

are roughly equivalent to:

```
a = b
if (b) { }
a = &c
while (&c) { }
```

which are the same as

```
a = b
if (a) { }
a = &c
while (a) { }
```

And what about those `if (a)` etc when they are not booleans? Well, if they are integers, 0 is false, the rest is true. This (one "zero" value -> false, the rest -> true) usually holds, **but** you should really refer to a C++ reference to be sure (however note that writting `if (a == 0)` is not much more difficult than `if (!a)`, being much simpler to the reader).

Anyways, **you should always avoid side-effects that obscure your code**.

You should **never** need to do `if (a = b)`: you can achieve exactly the same thing in other ways that are more clear and that won't look like a mistake (if I read a code like `if (a = b)` the first thing that comes to my mind is that the developper who wrote that made a mistake; the second, if I triple-check that it is correct, is that I hate him! :-)

Good luck

Comment: As a style convention, most compilers issue a warning for this case (something like "assignment in boolean context" or "did you mean ==?"), and many people use this style to denote that the assignment-as-test expression is intentional: `if( (a = b) ) { ... }`

Comment: I personally prefer `if (static_cast<bool>(a=b)) { }` - make the implicit cast explicit.

Comment: in case of some crazy overload operator= may return something other that reference to a, that is  (a=b)  is not equivalent to a. Ofc, in that case we should question sanity of author

Answer (score 5):

An assignment "operation" also returns a value.  It is the type and value of the expression.  If handled by an `if` type statement:

- `while (expr)`
- `do` ... `until (expr)`
- `if (expr)`
- or the ternary operator (expr) `?` (true value) : false value

expr is evaluated.  If it is nonzero, it is true.  If zero, it is false.

Answer (score 1):

The return type of the assignment is the left hand value, it's what allows statements like `a = b = c` to compile. In your example:

```
while(a = &c)
{
}
```

Returns true when "a" is true, after it has been assigned the value of &c.

Comment: It's the *new* left-hand value (or better said, the *result* of the assignment)

Comment: +1... To help clarify, your expression will be converted to an integral value, and if it is non-zero, the statement will be evaluated as 'true', if it is zero, as false.

Answer (score 0):

In both examples you listed, inside the parentheses is evaluated to true if a is non-zero after the assignment.

In a more common case, you compare a variable with a constant, to avoid this problem, some coding standards require that you write the constant first.

if (A_CONSTANT = var_a)

this would be caught by the compiler, whereas,

if (var_a = A_CONSTANT)

won't.

Comment: Some compilers issue a warning diagnostic. Perhaps not by default, but certainly on higher warning levels.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (a = b)
    ...
```

is the shorthand for:

```
a = b;
if (a != 0)
    ...
```

In a while statement, assignment within the condition enables the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle:

```
while (a = b)
{
    ...
}
```

is shorthand for (notice how I had to replicate the assignment so that it is done right before the condition check):

```
a = b;
while (a != 0)
{
    ...
    a = b;
}
```

That said, one classic issue with code like this is knowing whether the code intended to do an assignment or if the code forget an '=' when the intent was to write '==' (i.e. should that have been `while (a == b)`.

Because of this, you should never write just a plain assignment (gcc will issue a warning such as "suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value").  If you want to use assignment in a control structure, you should always surround it with extra parentheses and explicitly add the not-equal:

```
if ((a = b) != 0)
    ...

while ((a = b) != 0)
    ...
```

Comment: A world-class award-winning marvelous example of `how-not-to-write-code` and `code-that-seems-to-have-a-mistake`.

Comment: Maybe not exactly stated as above, but I think code with assignments inside a while() can make sense...  Especially something like while (p = enumerate_frobs(&frob_state)) { ... } where the name is something that makes it obvious that it follows an iterator-ish pattern.  With this in mind it seems unfair to downvote simply because the answer is describing something that *might* be misused but might also have a good use.

Answer (score 0):

An assignment statement evaluates to the new value of the variable assigned to (barring bizarre overloads of operator=). If the assignment happens in a boolean context it will then depend on the type of that value how it is treated. If the value is a bool, it is of course treated as a bool. If the value is a numeric value, a non-zero value is treated as true. If the value is a pointer, a non-NULL value is treated as true. If it is a object, the compiler will attempt to convert it to a boolean value (e.g. operator bool). If that is not possible, the compiler will attempt to convert the object to a value that is convertible to bool (e.g. a pointer type, or a numeric type such as int). Finally, if there is no conversion to be performed, or there are multiple possible conversions (e.g. the object defines operator int and operator foo*), the code will fail to compile.