# Trivial topic, does an assignment return 'false'?

Tags: c++

In this, the result is 6. But isn't i=5 considered a non-zero value? If I do i+=5 then it counts it as true. Why is this any different?  (also no, I didn't mean to put i==5)

```
int i=7;
if(i=5) {
cout << ++i;
} else {
cout << --i;
}
```

Comment: isn't 6 an expected result? Expression `i=5` is non-zero, result of `cout << ++i;` is 6 (5+1) sent to cout.

Comment: Same question has been answered before on stackoverflow. 
[Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003895/in-c-what-causes-an-assignment-to-evaluate-as-true-or-false-when-used-in-a-con) it is.

Comment: Just a hint: if it's trivial, it has probably been asked before. Searching may save you some down votes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment operators like `=` and `+=` return the value of the object after it's been assigned to. So, if you assign something `false` or `0`, you can get `false` from the assignment operator.

`i=5` evaluates to `5` and that's `true` in the eyes of `if ()`. But `i=0` would evaluate to `0` and that would be considered `false` by `if ()`.

Answer (score 3):

An assignment returns whatever was assigned. In your example:

```
int i = 7;
if (i = 5) { // returns 5, which is non-zero, or "true"
    cout << ++i; // prints 6, or 5+1
}  else {
    cout << --i; // would print 4, or 5-1, if it was hit, which it never will
}
```

You may be confused by pre-increment vs post-increment. For example, consider the following:

```
int i = 7;
if (i = 5) { // returns 5, which is non-zero, or "true"
    cout << i++; // prints 5, i is 6 after this line
}  else {
    cout << i--; // would print 5, but i is 4 after this line
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code acts like this:

```
i = 7;
i = 5;
if ( 5 ) // it's true. Isn't it ?
{
    i = i + 1; // now i is 6
    cout << i;
}
```