# New to C, Simple code not working

Tags: c, arrays, char

For some reason, the following code goes into an infinite loop.
I tried it without the "break;" after the if and else, with no luck.

Would highly appreciate a response! Thanks in advance :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> 
int main() // Very simple version of Bulls & Cows
{
 int j=0,k=0,bulls=0,cows=0;
 char random[5]="1234";
 char msg[100]="5678"; // I want it to be [100], I know it's not needed.
 printf("Bulls: %d  Cows: %d \n",bulls ,cows);
 for(k=0;k<4;k++)
 {
    for(j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
        if(msg[k]=msg[j])
        {
            if(k=j)
            {
                bulls++;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                cows++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
  printf("Bulls: %d  Cows: %d \n",bulls ,cows); //Just to see where is the problem
 }
 printf("Final Bulls: %d  Final Cows: %d \n",bulls ,cows);
}
```

Comment: `if(k=j)` You probably meant `if(k==j)`. `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison.

Comment: Also `if(msg[k]==msg[j])` above that.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings, some compilers will suggest parentheses for assignment used as a truth value.

Comment: As an aside, for being new to C and new to SO, thank you for providing your small, complete code with a description of what is wrong and what you expect to happen!

Comment: FYI, C != C++ and you should generally only tag the language you are writing/compiling. Someone has already removed the C++ tag for you, but you should remember this for future questions.

Comment: Thanks a bunch everyone!

Answer (score 3):

`=` is an assignment operator.

`==` is a comparison operator.

You want to use  `==`.

```
if (k == j) // note double =
if (msg[k] == msg[j]) // note double =
```

Comment: You left the mistake in the second case.

Comment: also worth noting that the assignment operator will return TRUE if right hand side is not zero (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003895/in-c-what-causes-an-assignment-to-evaluate-as-true-or-false-when-used-in-a-con)