# Short-circuit evaluation evaluating if( (a = 4) || (b = 6) || (c = 7) || (d = 8) )

Tags: c, if-statement, logical-operators

The program is posted below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a, b, c, d;

    printf("a = %d, b = %d, c = %d, d = %d\n", a, b, c, d);

    if( (a = 4) || (b = 6) || (c = 7) || (d = 8) )
        printf("a = %d, b = %d, c = %d, d = %d\n", a, b, c, d);
}
```

I understand the first printf statement but in the 2nd if statement I do not understand what it would evaluate when there is only one equal sign instead of two.

The output is :

```
        a = 0, b = 0, c = 32767, d = -341260496
        a = 4, b = 0, c = 32767, d = -341260496
```

So the 2nd if statement ended up being true but how?
I thought one equal sign would be assigning a value to the variables.

Comment: The first printf is undefined behavior, because you have not initialized any of the variables.

Comment: None of the variables are initialized. In the end, only `a` gets set to `4` while the others still remain uninitialized.

Comment: Use `==` to test for equality. `a = 4` assigns the value 4 to `a`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In C++ what causes an assignment to evaluate as true or false when used in a control structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003895/in-c-what-causes-an-assignment-to-evaluate-as-true-or-false-when-used-in-a-con)

Comment: one equal sign assigns then returns the assigned value (so it's `true` for the first assignment, the rest is skipped)

Comment: Only `a` gets assigned because it's a short circuit.  There's no point in looking at anything past the first `||` so those other assignments don't get executed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is short-circuiting logical operators mandated? And evaluation order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628526/is-short-circuiting-logical-operators-mandated-and-evaluation-order)

Answer (score 5):

> I do not understand what if would evaluate when there is only one equal sign instead of two.

One equal sign makes it an assignment. Hence, `a=4` evaluates to `4`, which is interpreted as "true" by the logical "OR" operator `||`. At this point no further evaluation is happening due to short-circuiting, so the remaining variables retain the values that they have prior to the `if` statement.

**Note:** Printing unassigned variables causes undefined behavior. You should change the declaration line as follows:

```
int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

This call of printf

```
    int a, b, c, d;

    printf("a = %d, b = %d, c = %d, d = %d\n", a, b, c, d);
```

has undefined behavior because variables a, b, c, and d are not initialized and have indeterminate values that can be trap values.

In the condition of the if statement

```
if( (a = 4) || (b = 6) || (c = 7) || (d = 8) )
```

there is assignment expression

```
a = 4
```

According to the C Standard (6.5.16 Assignment operators)

> 3 An assignment operator stores a value in the object designated by
>   the left operand. **An assignment expression has the value of the left
>   operand after the assignment**,111) but is not an lvalue...

And further (6.5.14 Logical OR operator)

> 3 The || operator shall yield 1 if either of its operands compare
>   unequal to 0; otherwise, it yields 0. The result has type int.
>   4 Unlike the bitwise | operator, the || operator guarantees
>   left-to-right evaluation; if the second operand is evaluated, there is
>   a sequence point between the evaluations of the first and second
>   operands. **If the first operand compares unequal to 0, the second
>   operand is not evaluated.**

Thus only the assignment

```
a = 4
```

will be performed in this if statement

```
if( (a = 4) || (b = 6) || (c = 7) || (d = 8) )
```

all other variables still will be uninitialized.

As the value of the assignment that is 4 is not equal to 0 then the if sub-statement will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

> So the 2nd if statement ended up being true but how?

In C, assignments are also a sort of expression that evaluate to some value. The value is (in most situations) the right hand side of the assignment.

In this case, `(a = 4)` evaluates to 4, which is `true` in the world of C, thus short-circuiting the entire condition and skipping the assignments for `b`, `c` and `d`. Which is why only `a` is initialised while the others retain their junk values.

Comment: "The value is always the right hand side of the assignment."  Hmmm. Not quite.  Try `int i;
  float f = (i = 1.23);
  printf("%f\n", f);` . `(i = 1.23)` evaluates to `(int) 1`.

Comment: @chux Woah, that's neat.

Answer (score 1):

In short, when you compare using OR,  evaluation is done until the 1st occurrence of TRUE. So only a=4 is assigned. Rest are still uninitialized.