# Why is (n = 0) == 0?

Tags: c, if-statement, variable-assignment

Can somone please explain me whats the reason behing this code and why does it print b

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    n = 0;
    if (n = 0)
        printf("a \n");
    else
        printf("b \n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (n = 0)` assigns 0 to variable n and returns 0, so condition is false

Comment: Try `if (n == 0)` instead.

Comment: Here is a fun story about the time someone tried to use this to insert a backdoor into the Linux kernel: https://freedom-to-tinker.com/2013/10/09/the-linux-backdoor-attempt-of-2003/

Answer (score 3):

This instruction

```
if (n = 0) printf("a \n");
```

will do 2 things:

1. assign 0 to `n`
2. 'return' 0 from the assignment (this is the reason behind multiple inline assignment like `a = b = c`: `b = c` will first assign to b the value of c, and than this will return the value of c, which will be also assigned to a)

Because of the second point, that instruction is the same of

```
if (0) printf("a \n");
```

And in C the 0 is evaluated as false, so this is the reason behind the printing of `b` instead of `a`.

Take in mind that the `equal operator` in C and in most of the languages is `==`, where instead `=` is the assigning operator, so if you want to check is `n` is 0 you should have done this:

```
if (n == 0)
    printf("a \n");
else
    printf("b \n");
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not an equality check, but an assignment.

The expression `n = 0` evaluates to the value of the right-hand expression (or `0`). Since `0` is considered false, the first condition is skipped and `b` is printed.

What you really wanted to do was this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n = 0;

    if (n == 0) /* notice: == */
        printf("a \n");
    else
        printf("b \n");
    return 0;
}
```

Here `==`, the equality operator, is used.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the line:

```
if (n = 0)
```

A single `=` is used for assigning variables. `==` is how you compare equality in c.
So if you replace

```
if (n = 0)
```

with

```
if (n == 0)
```

then you should get "a" as your output

Comment: the part: `replace n = 0 with n == 0 then you should get b` is not correct.

Comment: just a language correction, = is used for ASSIGNING variables, you can define variables withouth assigning them.

Comment: my apologies your correct @Bwebb still a beginner myself cheers for the feedback! ill update now

Answer (score 1):

Because:

```c
(n = 0) == 0
```

The `=` is the assignment operator in C, which assigns `0` to `n` and [evaluates to the value being attributed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2003920/3215929). In this case `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `n = 0` is an expression that performs an assignment, two things happen,

- n is assigned value 0
- expression `n = 0` evaluates to 0

This is why some advise writing comparisons as,

```
if( 0 == n ) print("a\n");
```

So that `=` cannot accidentally be used when `==` was intended.

And why some compilers warn to write assignments (where you want both behaviors) as,

```
if( (n = 0) ) print("a\n");
```